# Browse for image on Phone Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I am creating Windows Phone 7 application. So far I've got login to Facebook account and post text to my wall. I want now upload image to my feed/album.

How can I browse for image on the phone and then selected image upload to Facebook feed/album?

Regars

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this code somewhere in your application:

```
public void ShowPhotoChooser()
{
    PhotoChooserTask photoChooserTask = new PhotoChooserTask();
    photoChooserTask.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(photoChooserTask_Completed);
    photoChooserTask.Show();
}


void photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
    if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
    {
        System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bmp = 
          new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
        bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes it does, although it will only show the default picture library

Comment: it lives in my snippet library, i use it all the time

Answer (score 3):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769543(v=vs.92).aspx#BKMK_Photo

Should contain all you need to know.

Cheers!

Comment: I might just mention here that that wasn't a hard Google: http://www.google.com/?q=wp7%20choose%20a%20picture